# Adding a 120V circuit to a 240V 3-wire water well service

Tags: electrical

I would like to add a 120V 15A service at the well head to run a charcoal filtration system. The well area is remote from the house and is 3-wire 240V without a neutral. Can I use one of the 120V legs and existing ground wire as the neutral for the outlet? Installing the filter at the house poses space limitations.

Comment: No but we have a few other tricks. What  is the breaker size, wire size and rating on the pump?

Comment: What wiring method was used to run the wire out to the wellhouse?

Comment: Breaker for the well is 30A. Wiring is #6 run hopefully run full length in conduit, I've never dug up the 150' feed to see if it's direct burial between the risers. It was built in 2002 to applicable codes so I'm surprised they didn't run a 4-wire circuit. The charcoal filtration has less than a 5A current draw, enough to run sensors and a relay to the automatic backwash.